# Excel: how to find the intersection (equilibrium point) between supply and demand?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column indicating the demand over time, a column indicating the supply cumulative volume available (always the same regardless of the time) and the price corresponding to each supply volume.

It looks like this:

```
demand supply price
30     5      3    
12     10     7
13     15     11
23     20     13
3      25     15
22     30     21
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
```

I need in a new column, for each demand volume, the clearing price of the corresponding supply volume capable to satisfy the demand (for example in the 3rd row, the cleared price=15 is the price associated to a supply=25 which is the minimum greater volume capable to cover the demand=23). This would result as:

```
demand supply price    cleared price
    18     5      3      13
    12     10     7      11
    13     15     11     11
    23     20     13     15  
    3      25     15     3
    20     30     21     13
    .      .      .      .
    .      .      .      .
    .      .      .      .
```

I am trying with functions as: LOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH...for instance tryiong to find the smallest positive difference between supply and demand, but at the moment I'm struggling in finding a solution. Anyone has ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you specify in further detail how the `cleared price` is calculated? Ideally in a mathematical formula fashion

Comment: Potentially a case for Solver.

Comment: The cleared price is that price which is associated to the supply volume capable to cover the demand (for example in the 3rd row, the cleared price=11 is the price associated to a supply=15 which is the minimum greater volume capable to cover the demand=13). I did it manually in this example, but over a column with hundreds of values this is impossible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if *demand* in column A, *price* in column C and *cleared price* (to find out) in column D you could use :

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$128, IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$128,1)),1, IF(INDEX($B$2:$B$128,MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$128,1))=A2,MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$128,1),MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$128,1)+1)))
```

Comment: Yes, I think we did something similar!

Comment: similar, but not the same. you weren't managing the case _demand_ is smaller than minimum _supply_

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed now to do something close to what I want doing:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$128;IFNA(MATCH(D2;$G$2:$G$128;1)+1;1))
```

MATCH is used to find out which row of the supply is greater than the demand (I add 1 because it didn't work with "greater than", so I use "smaller than" and I select the next row)

IFNA corrects to 1 those values that because of the function "smaller than" were N/A, as the demand was smaller than any possible supply.

INDEX associates the price to the MATCH result.

I still have to go through the list, but it seems to be all right.